# day of the week error handling

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm new to pandas and trying to get the day of the week from a time stamp.

I have the following DF

```
    Date    Open    High
0   2015-07-13  532.880005  547.109985
1   2015-07-14  546.760010  565.848999
2   2015-07-15  560.130005  566.502991
3   2015-07-16  565.119995  580.679993
4   2015-07-17  649.000000  674.468018
```

I want to know which day of the week it happened, I did the following:

```
G['weekday'] = G['Date'].dt.dayofweek()
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-b3724388eff0> in <module>()
----> 1 G['weekday'] = G['Date'].dt.dayofweek()

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `df['Date'].dt.dayofweek` returns a Series. Instead do:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofweek
```

```
>>> df
        Date        Open        High  weekday
0 2015-07-13  532.880005  547.109985        0
1 2015-07-14  546.760010  565.848999        1
2 2015-07-15  560.130005  566.502991        2
3 2015-07-16  565.119995  580.679993        3
4 2015-07-17  649.000000  674.468018        4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! is there a chance you can explain the difference between the 2 options? again thank you so much!

Comment: Anytime you have `()` at the end of something you're calling it.

Comment: I hope I'm making at least some sense.

Comment: that makes perfect sense! thank you again for your quick help!